# Review enforcement

Tags: discussion, review

The site has a user who has very high review stats in several queues. And his usual review answers are "Looks OK", "Leave Open", "Repoen", etc.

https://economics.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history

This results in extremely low quality questions such as [this one](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19736/homework-help-marginal-abatement-cost-and-pollution-quantity) being given the all clear.

Is there any solution to this problem other than trying to review questions faster?

EDIT:

 An example of my problem:

[image]

All these review votes came from the same user. Six reviews in one minute. Four of these votes went against the majority opinion of other reviewers.

Comment: Can't a Leave Open vote be overruled by a sufficient number of Close votes?  I have always assumed this to be the case, but I couldn't find this stated anywhere in Help.

Comment: Leave Open and Repoen votes can indeed be overruled. Unfortunately AFAIK for first posts only one reviewer is required.

Comment: I'm not aware of any precedents for dealing with this kind of issue, nor is their an obvious answer to myself. I can look into it more and ask the mods from other stacks about it if you like.

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry Personally I perceive this as a problem, albeit not a serious one. It is up to the site and its elected mods :) how they wish to deal with it. Unfortunately I have no suggestions either.

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry As for precedents: There [is a user who I am pretty sure is a script](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/does-stackexchange-screen-suspicious-voting-behavior).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you see this sort of thing, please feel free to flag one of their posts for moderator attention and ask them to look into the user's review history.

The site diamond moderators have the ability to investigate these incidents and, if there is any indication of poor behavior, ban users from review. These bans generally start at three days and can go up to a year or more. Hopefully the first request to take more time with reviews will change the behavior without requiring a longer ban.

As to other solutions, in most cases, a single user doing a poor job of reviewing won't be enough to do too much damage. The queue that requires the fewest reviewers is the suggested edit queue which calls for two "approve" or one "improve edit" vote.

For those not sure how to properly review posts, there's a guide on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing) that might help. The most important thing to remember is to actually read the post and judge it on its merits: If it needs editing, edit; if it needs to be closed, vote to close; if it needs to be removed, recommend deletion. Keeping the site clean and neat is an important part of every site's moderation and we hope users will take those moderation tasks seriously.

This can be easy to miss, so thanks for pointing it out.